# Automatic dicer

Tags: equipment, vegetables, cutting

I love cooking, but I hate dicing! I have a food processor that can slice really well, but it doesn't have any ability to do dicing.

Does a device that can automatically dice various produce (peppers, potatoes, carrots, that sort of thing) exist?

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, dicing is very quick and easy if you use a good sharp knife and the proper technique.  I strongly suggest having a look through our [knife-skills](/questions/tagged/knife-skills) questions and in particular ones like [How to dice tomatoes?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/3195/41).  I guarantee that with a little practice, you'll get better, more consistent results than any overpriced kitchen gadget.  A good chef's knife is the better investment.

Nevertheless, on the days that I am feeling *incredibly* lazy or am running particularly short on time, I'll sometimes resort to using my [Progressive Onion Chopper](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000A389IM).  Note that I'm on my 3rd one now; they're made of plastic and tend to break easily if you apply too much pressure (which you sometimes can't avoid doing if you want to actually make a clean cut).  I really do not recommend these for heavy-duty or prolonged use; as I said above, they're useful for the occasional bout of extreme laziness.

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with Aaronut about getting better with knife skills as the best option, but for lazy night I have a device similar to the onion chopper he mentioned as well.  It does its job, but most of the time I find that it's easier to use my knife than it is to clean it.

If you're looking for something heavy duty and have money to burn, there is a series of devices that I've seen in the back of house at plenty of restaurants, for example the [Nemco Easy Chopper](http://www.nemcofoodequip.com/Products/FoodPrepEquip/EasyChopper.aspx) ([Video of it in action](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2lbypkET7BU)).  They're going to set you back anywhere from $150-$200 though.

On [this page](http://www.nemcofoodequip.com/Products/FoodPrepEquip/Default.aspx) you can search by what you want to cut and what type of cut you want to make to find something that suits your needs.